# let $α, β ∈\operatorname{ End}(V )$ satisfy $3α^3 + 7α^2 − 2αβ + 4α − σ_1 = σ_0$. Show that $αβ = βα$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I need some help with this problem please:

Let $V$ be a vector space finitely generated over $\mathbb Q$ and
let $α, β ∈ \operatorname{ End}(V )$ satisfy $3α^3 + 7α^2 − 2αβ + 4α − σ_1 = σ_0$. Show that $αβ = βα$.

Thanks.

This is an exercise from the book: The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Should Know by Golan.

Comment: What is $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_0$? Identity and zero-map?

Comment: That is right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 
$$\alpha\cdot(3\alpha^2+7\alpha-2\beta+4)=\sigma_1 $$
we conclude that $\alpha$ is invertible. But then this right-inverse must also be a left-inverse *(here we use that $\dim V<\infty$)*, i.e.,
$$(3\alpha^2+7\alpha-2\beta+4)\cdot\alpha=\sigma_1 $$
Subtracting these equations we obtain $2\alpha\beta-2\beta\alpha=\sigma_0$, hence $\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha$. *(We made little use of the fact that the base field is $\mathbb Q$; all we needed was charactiristic $\ne 2$ in order to divide by $2$ in the last step)*

Comment: Very clear, thanks a lot.